# How to group the elements of my list?

Tags: python, list

i had a list:

```
    list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

how would I go about converting this list to:

```
    list = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your own code and explanation of what it is that is giving you issues in your current implementation.

Comment: does the list always have an even number of elements?

Comment: How to group: Build always pairs? Build always 3 groups? What if the list isn't 6 elements in size?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
>>> li=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> ['{}{}'.format(a,b) for a,b in zip(li, li[1:])]
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef']
```

Or:

```
>>> [a+b for a,b in zip(li, li[1:])]
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef']
```

Or, if you want `['ab', 'cd', 'ef']` you can do:

```
>>> [a+b for a,b in zip(*[iter(li)]*2)]
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

Or,

```
>>> [a+b for a,b in zip(li[::2],li[1::2])]
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

For a different group length:

```
>>> [''.join(l) for l in zip(*[iter(li)]*3)]
['abc', 'def']
```

(And please don't use `list` as a name for a list. You clobber the function by the same name)

Comment: I hope this is not the starting point for a grouping strategies database ;)

Comment: The desired output is `['ab', 'cd', 'ef']` and not `['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef']`

Comment: @MoeA What makes you sure about this?

Comment: @Wolf its mentioned in the question?

Comment: How would i be able to do the last one if i wasnt sure how many elements will be in the list? Automate it in a sense?

Comment: @zanmerc: I don't follow your question. None of those is dependent on the number in the list. However, if the number in the list won't make a full pair such as `['a', 'b', 'c']` then the return is `['ab']` Would you want `['ab','c']`?

Comment: @dawg: sorry i wasnt clear, basically i need the groupings to be different depending on how many elements in the list. for example, if theres 4 elements i need to group them in two's or if there were 6 elements i'd need to group them in 3's. Would that be possible?

Comment: @zanmerc: Yes. With `[a+b for a,b in zip(*[iter(li)]*2)]` Just have the `2` be a dynamic value that is set based on the length of the list. Such as `[a+b for a,b in zip(*[iter(li)]*len(li)/2]`

Comment: @dawg: everything works perfectly here, except for the "a+b for a,b" part, if the sets are based on length how can I avoid having to change the a+b part since the sets will not always be split into 2's? Thanks alot for your help by the way, sorry to bother you!

Comment: Ahh -- got ya. Use `join`: `[''.join(l) for l in zip(*[iter(li)]*gr_len)]`

Answer (score 1):

```py
def pairs(sequence):
    sequence = iter(sequence)
    while True:
        yield next(sequence) + next(sequence)

>>> list(pairs(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
['ab', 'cd']
>>> list(pairs(['a', 'b', 'c']))
['ab']
```

Note that it would ignore elements when the total number is not even.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways, here is one:

```
[n for n in map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], zip(list[::2], list[1::2]))]
```

Reason I don't use `list()` to force output is because you are occupying it, which is not recommended. If you rename your `list` to `ls`, here is a shorter version:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], zip(ls[::2], ls[1::2])))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. i just tried this, and when i tried to print i got this: 
<map object at 0x500952c> , how can i get it to actually print?

Comment: I have updated for your case (python3). Usually you can call `list()` to force output but as you are already using it as your data variable, I used a different method of dumping.